How do I fix this in my SQL, it has a problem with character type: ' ', in my first one for metro it doesn't return
cod_cli = df\['cod_cli'\].tolist()

cod_cli_str = ','.join(map(str, cod_cli))

\# clientesAtacado =

query = f"""

select \* from P_VTVVIEDB.VBRA_CITY

where bracityid in (select bracityid

from P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_ADDRESS

where swobjectid in (select swsiteid from P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_SITE where swcustomerid in

(SELECT swcustomerid FROM P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_CUSTOMER WHERE CONCAT('40',left(TELCNPJ,8)) IN (${cod_cli_str}))))

;

my return the query it's this:
Bad character in format or data of SW_CUSTOMER.TELCNPJ.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.formatError ErrorUtil.go:85


HOw is  SW_CUSTOMER.TELCNPJ defined (data type)?  What does the left function return?

# assume cod_cli as list of strings
cod_cli_str = ','.join(f"'{item}'" for item in cod_cli) #format each item as string literal

query = f"""
select * from P_VTVVIEDB.VBRA_CITY
where bracityid in (
    select bracityid
    from P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_ADDRESS
    where swobjectid in (
        select swsiteid 
        from P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_SITE 
        where swcustomerid in (
            SELECT swcustomerid 
            FROM P_VTVVIEDB.VSW_CUSTOMER 
            WHERE CONCAT('40', left(TRIM(TELCNPJ), 8)) IN (${cod_cli_str})
        )
    )
);



make sure TELCNPJ is a string or converted/cast to a string
CONCAT('40', left(TELCNPJ, 8)) result has to match format of values in cod_cli_str
adjust query to wrap each item in '' to make sure SQL process them as string
Used TRIM to remove unexpected white space [you can choose to handle more unexpected values]


Thanks for helping, but it still gave an error, I think the problem is in teradata

try to concat using || , WHERE '40' || TRIM(CAST(TELCNPJ AS CHAR(18))) IN ({cod_cli_str})
